# How can I replicate the StackOverflow questions list format?

Tags: php, html, css

I have data being pulled from the database onto the front-end, but each entry is appearing in the same location and overlapping. How do I have my data displayed in a list in a similar way to StackOverflow's 'Top Questions' list?

Here is my code:

```
      <?php

      include 'main.html';

      include 'dbconnect.php';

      $findPosts = "SELECT * FROM Posts";
      $showPosts = mysqli_query($db, $findPosts) or die(mysqli_error);

      while ($currentrow = mysqli_fetch_array($showPosts)) {

      echo '<a href="http://www.youtube.com"      id="PostTitle">'.$currentrow['Title'].'</a>';


      echo '<p id="Date">'.$currentrow['Date'].'</p>';
      }

      ?>
```

And here is my css:

```
#PostBox{
  position: fixed;
  left: 200px;
  top: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  } 

#PostTitle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 272px;
  left: 120px;
  font-family: helvetica neue;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #0066CC;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#Date {
  font-family: helvetica neue;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 302px;
  left: 120px;
  color: #696969;
  text-decoration: bold;
}
```

Comment: Unless you provide the CSS, sorry, we can't help. CSS positions everything, and **you are duplicating `id`s**.

Comment: Everything is position fixed, and with the same coordinates. you are placing everything in the same place. Remove "position:fixed" from everywhere. As @PraveenKumar mentioned, make them classes, not id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `position: fixed` in CSS, because this will place all related elements on the same place, even if you are scrolling. Then also `left` and `top` are not important.

It would be a good idea to put every Post in a div Box:

```
  <?php

  include 'main.html';

  include 'dbconnect.php';

  $findPosts = "SELECT * FROM Posts";
  $showPosts = mysqli_query($db, $findPosts) or die(mysqli_error);

  while ($currentrow = mysqli_fetch_array($showPosts)) {

      echo '<div class="box">';
      echo '<a href="http://www.youtube.com" class="PostTitle">'.$currentrow['Title'].'</a>';
      echo '<p class="Date">'.$currentrow['Date'].'</p>';
      echo '</div>';
  }

  ?>
```

And the you can change your CSS like this:
(You can delete the CSS for `.box` if you want, because it is only to make the box for every post visible.)

```
.box{
   margin:2px;
   background-color:#cccccc;
}

.PostTitle {
  font-family: helvetica neue;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #0066CC;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.Date {
  color: #696969;
  text-decoration: bold;
}
```

Of you want define the place of `Date` and `PostTitle`, relative to its `box`, you can:

```
.box{
  position:relative;
}
.PostTitle{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.Date{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - all fixed!